# Sequencer checkpoint run in datastage

Tags: datastage

Suppose I have 5 activity stages in sequence  in a Datastage sequencer job. I have checked the box "Do not checkpoint run" for activity 2 and 4 stages. For other activity stages the box is not checked. Suppose if the sequencer fails at activity5. In normal case upon restart it should start from activity5. But here will the sequencer start  from activity 2 since I have checked the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - if you check "Do not checkpoint run" the activity will be run at every restart. So in your case after an abort of activity 5:

- Activity 2 will be started because "Do not checkpoint run" is checked
- Activity 4 will be started because "Do not checkpoint run" is checked
- Activity 5 will be started because it aborted previously

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir. It was hard for me to.try this in.machine because in our project the do not checkpoint run has been disabled from checking.